# Unexpected SYSDATE behavior

Tags: oracle, exadata

I have a SQL trigger which adds the old value ,new value and time of update for column based on update, insert, update or delete.

To update the time we used `SYSDATE`and inserted record from trigger. This trigger was working fine for a long time. Few weeks back the server is upgraded to Exadata from 11g and now are experiencing some issues. The column inserted by `SYSDATE` is expected to update GMT time. But only in some cases it does insert central time and this behavior is intermittent. We also tried updating the table from same machine and experienced the same issue. So now we suspect it may be Exadata upgrade, but we are not sure. So does anyone has experienced similar issue or have any idea why this is happening.

Comment: `SYSDATE` uses the Linux boxes timezone. I suspect the timezone on one of the exadata blades is incorrect.